# Cortex-A8 Forcing memory caching

Tags: c++, c, caching, cortex-a8

It's necessary process a big array of numbers (~1 Mb) in real time with a function e.g. `void processData(char* data)`.

There following test was runned on the target platform:

```
int j = 10;
while(j--)
    processData(dataPtr);
```

with the same data every time. It showed the following result:

1. 1st run takes ~22.5ms
2. 2nd run and others take ~12,5ms

In my opinion it can be caused by the fact that on the 2nd run data is already in processor cache, thus it works much faster.

The problem: in real case, data will be every time different.

Is there any way to make a kind of "preload" of data to cache?

Comment: You have to pay for memory bandwidth/latency at least once when you access previously uncached data, so in general it makes no overall difference if you load it via prefetch instructions or via load instructions.

Comment: I can't see it being a good idea to preload the contents manually unless you have spare CPU cycles at all times except all of a sudden you need to run your data (that was previously available) through and get the results now... if you're preloading one dataset on the side while dealing with another, be careful not to end up forcing the data for the current iteration out of the cache to speed up the next, and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

Prefetching is possible (with `gcc`, use `__builtin_prefetch`), but should be used carefully, or it may degrade performance rather than improve it.

Before doing it, the memory access pattern in the function should be inspected and optimized if possible.
Basically, we want as few memory accesses as possible, and they should be serial as much as possible.

There's a prefetch operation, but doing it for the entire data set isn't recommended.
A better design would, in every iteration in a loop, prefetch data for the next iteration (or maybe the one after that, if the loop runs very fast).

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is keeping in mind that your whole working set fits LLC, you call the first run a 'warm-up run' and you don't take it's timing into account. Of course, this approach is reasonable if the third, fourth and further run timings are consistent with what the second run shows. Then, when you report benchmarking results, you show an average of 2-Nth runs timings, but you mention in the report that data fits L3 and different results are to be expected with more-'real-world data'. I think this is normally called micro-benchmarking, when you're testing the performance of one particular function over the same well-defined constant data set.